# What is the plural form of: unit of measure

Tags: grammatical-number

So, basically I want to know, how to pluralize the phrase `Unit of measure`

I have a group or collection of unit of measure like `liter, micro-liter, kilo`, etc and I want to given to that collection a correct title.

Is `Unit of measurements` correct? or `Unit of measures`?

Comment: Units of measure

Comment: Those are all *measurement units*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole batch of them constitute *units of measurement*. The prepositional clause would have a different meaning if rendered *of measurements* (referring to multiple actions of measuring),  so there is no choice for the plural of *unit of measurement*.

Comment: So, the correct title for a collection would be `Units of measurement`?

Comment: Also, How do you interprete the phrase `Unit of measures`?

Comment: To answer your first question, yes, that's what I wrote (*whole batch*). As to your second, I have no idea what it is supposed to mean.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I having a hard time naming collections in English, is easy if the object name is just one word, like `product` or `brand`. But with phrase like `unit of measure` or `bill of material`, I don't know how to treat them.

Comment: Can you give me one more example of how to name a collection of `bill of materials`?

Comment: Bills of materials or bills of material.